# Laravel custom Login Throttling

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to add Login Throttling to my custom login code. I use an email and a password for the login. Here is what i did:
I added

```
    use ThrottlesLogins; 
    protected $maxLoginAttempts=3;
    protected $lockoutTime=20;
```

at the beginning of my class, and then in my login method i did:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }
```

If the login fails i add

```
$this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
```

if it succeed I add

```
$this->clearLoginAttempts($request);
```

The problem though i'm getting:

```
Undefined method LoginController::username
```

I'm guessing it is because i use an email instead of a username for login.  What is the solution for this?

Comment: its because something is calling the `user` method that doesn't exist on this controller, you can use the stack trace to find the offending code

Comment: the throttling code needs this method but i don't have it and it should not need it

Comment: sorry meant the `username` method ... `ThrottlesLogins` trait is meant to be used specifically with the `LoginController` (which uses the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait) as it is provided ... so yea it uses the `username` method, so you should define one, or use the default `LoginController` or don't use the trait, or override the method that needs to call `username` etc etc etc

Comment: What should username method contain?

Comment: hasTooManyLoginAttempts is the method that's causing the problem

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating "Username Customization"

Comment: Perfect, worked. If you want just write this as the correct answer and i'll flag it so. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular trait, `ThrottlesLogins`, is meant to be used for the default `LoginController` that uses the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait, which provides a `username` method.

You can define this method yourself:

```
/**
 * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function username()
{
    return 'email';
}
```